# PHP if string contains URL isolate it

Tags: php, url, string

In PHP, I need to be able to figure out if a string contains a URL. If there is a URL, I need to isolate it as another separate string.

For example: "SESAC showin the Love! http://twitpic.com/1uk7fi"

I need to be able to isolate the URL in that string into a new string. At the same time the URL needs to be kept intact in the original string. Follow?

I know this is probably really simple but it's killing me.

Comment: Got it working, thanks you artifacto. Thanks everyone else for the contribution.

Comment: Can you possibly share the code? I've been looking all over for this.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Something like

```
preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]+:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z;.\/?:@=_#&%~,+$]+/', $string, $matches);
```

`$matches[0]` will hold the result.

(Note: this regex is certainly not RFC compliant; it may fetch malformed (per the spec) URLs. See http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc1738.html).

Comment: +1 Nice. Would you care to add a version that listens to `http` only for the sake of future generations?

Comment: The scheme is `[a-z]`. There can neither be uppercase letters nor digits in the scheme part of a URL. And frankly, there aren't too many valid schemes to begin with.

Comment: @Tomalak Yes, but sometimes people write HTTP://, it was supposed to capture that. I'll remove the digits.

Comment: @Pekka Without username, password, or fragments and in the same permissive spirit of the answer, something like `http(?:s)?://[a-zA-Z\-.]{3,}(?::\d+)?(?:/[a-zA-Z0-9$\-_.+!*'(),%/;:@&=]*(?:\?[a-zA-Z0-9$\-_.+!*'(),%;:@&=]*)?)?` (untested)

Comment: I cannot edit the comment anymore, but the hostname part is missing numbers.

Comment: I'm using this regex to find http and https '#\bhttps?://[^\s()<>]+(?:\([\w\d]+\)|([^[:punct:]\s]|/))#'

Comment: what about a simple
`www.example.com` that won't work

Answer (score 2):

this doesn't account for dashes -. needed to add -

```
preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]+:\/\/[0-9a-zA-Z;.\/\-?:@=_#&%~,+$]+/', $_POST['string'], $matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

URLs can't contain spaces, so...

```
\b(?:https?|ftp)://\S+
```

Should match any URL-like thing in a string.

The above is the pure regex. PHP preg_* *and* string escaping rules apply before you can use it.

Answer (score -1):

```
$test = "SESAC showin the Love! http://twitpic.com/1uk7fi";
$myURL= strstr ($test, "http");
echo $myURL; // prints http://twitpic.com/1uk7fi
```

Comment: No good: Will not parse URLs sans http, and will catch `http` even if used outside a URL context.