# fetch a URL from a string PHP

Tags: php, regex

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP if string contains URL isolate it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985465/php-if-string-contains-url-isolate-it)

I would like to use some kind of regex to extract any type of links like www.google.com or http://google.com or https://google.com or just google.com from a string

I have used something like this..but it only detects links with http and https

```
$regex ="/(https?:\/\/[^\s]+)/";
$string ="is there a link http://google.com in this string?";
preg_match($regex, $string,$matches);
print_r($matches);
```

The output I get is

```
Array ( [0] => http://google.com)
```

I want to detect all types of possible links in a string.

Any help will be appreciated!! :)

Comment: There are several other references. Search this site for `[php] preg_match url`

Comment: I don't think that this is an exact duplicate of the linked questions. The OP wants to cover more link patterns and the given link will not help the OP.

Answer (score 1):

I replace all URL with hyperlink but you can do whatever you want.

```
function formatUrlsInText($text)
{

    $reg_exUrl = "%^((http|https|ftp|ftps?://)|(www\.))([a-z0-9-].?)+(:[0-9]+)?(/.*)?$%i";
    preg_match_all($reg_exUrl, $text, $matches);
    $usedPatterns = array();
    foreach($matches[0] as $pattern){
        if(!array_key_exists($pattern, $usedPatterns)){
            $usedPatterns[$pattern]=true;
            $text = str_replace  ($pattern, "<a href='{$pattern}' rel='nofollow' target='_blank'>{$pattern}</a> ", $text);
        }
    }
    return $text;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make use of alternations to cover the other patterns. Try something like this:

```
(https?:\/\/[^\s]+|\bwww\.[^\s]+|[^\s]+\.(?:com|org|uk)\b)
```

See it here [online on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2urnu)

The first part is yours. The second part will match everything that starts with `www.` and the third part will match everything that ends with something from this list (com|org|uk). You can add any domain you want to match to this list.

I am quite sure this will match a lot of stuff thats not a valid URL, but if you are happy with your Regex, probably the other two patterns are also fine for your need.