# Linking URL in middle of string

Tags: php, html

Wondering how I would detect a URL in a string and return a link. Example

> $text = 'Go to www.example.com example.com example.net http://example.com';
>       echo $text;

would return

> Go to www.example.com example.com
>   etc.

Comment: I would use the search either on this website or on google to locate the highest rated answer on stackoverflow that solves the issue for me. But that might just be personal preference. You can also continue to wonder and wait that users here start to provide hacky code and half-ready solutions just by pure coincidence because they have just spotted you asking for it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP if string contains URL isolate it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2985465/php-if-string-contains-url-isolate-it)

Answer (score 1):

You could use RegEx, or you could explode the $text string on spaces and then check with substring each exploded word if they begin with http://, https:// or end in .com, .net, .org and wrap that string in a link

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it.

It will echo `http://google.com` from

> www.website.com and example.com BUT http://google.com and now
>   www.website.com

```
<?php
$x = "www.website.com and example.com and 
      even http://google.com and now www.website.com I could go on forever";

 $start = strpos($x, 'http://');
    for($i=$start; $i < strlen($x); $i++){

        if(strpos($x, '.com') == true) {
            $str = strpos($x, '.com');
                echo $x[$i];
        if($x[$i] === ' '){
            break;
        }
    }
}
```